# Video not uploading via php

Tags: php, mysql, upload

First of all, here's my code from the first, form, page:

```
    <form method="POST" action="uploadMovieProcess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">



    <br><br>
    <label for="movieTitle" class="thicker4">Movie Title: </label><input type="text" 
    id="movieTitle" name="movieTitle" size="50" placeholder="E.g. Hobbit An Unexpected Journey, The"/>

    <br><br>
    <label for="movieUrl" class="thicker4">Movie File Name: </label><input type="text" 
    id="movieUrl" name="movieUrl" size="50" onkeyup="nospaces(this)" placeholder="E.g. hobbitAnUnexpectedJourney,The.mp4"/>


    <br><br><text class="thicker4">Upload Movie Here: </text>
 <input type="file" name="movieUrl" id="movieUrl">
 <value="movieUrl" name="submit">
    <p class="thicker3">Or drag and drop on top of the choose file button</p>

     <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

And here's my code from the second, process, page:

```
    // this handles the video

    $target_dir = "movies/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["movieUrl"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $videoFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "This film is already on this database, or atleast there's a file with the same name...";
$uploadOk = 0;
    }

     // Allow certain file formats
     if($videoFileType != "mp4" && $videoFileType != "ogg" && $videoFileType != "eog"
    && $videoFileType != "webm" ) {
   echo "Sorry, only MP4, Ogg, Eog & WebM formats are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
     }



     // this handles the database

     $movieTitle=$_POST["movieTitle"];   
    $movieUrl=$_POST["movieUrl"]; 

    $mysqlserver="localhost"; 
    $mysqlusername="jakedean";
    $mysqlpassword="jakedean";
    $link=mysql_connect($mysqlserver, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die    ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

    $dbname = 'allMovies';
     mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified         database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());
        // the query which inserts the new data (from the variables) is set up and run

     $addMoviequery="INSERT INTO movies 
(movieTitle, movieUrl)
VALUES 
('$movieTitle', 'movies/$movieUrl')";
    mysql_query($addMoviequery) or die("Query to insert new movie into movies failed with this error: ".mysql_error());            

echo "<button class=\"buttonStyle\" onclick=\"location.href='index.php'\">Or, Click here</button>";

    echo "<p class=\"thicker2\">You Added a new movie! The information of   this movie is:</p>
            <p class=\"bold\">Movie Title:</p> <p class=\"thicker\">$movieTitle</p> 
    <p class=\"bold\">Movie File Name:</p> <p class=\"thicker\">$movieUrl</p>"
    ?>
```

In my console I'm getting no errors, the variables are being inserted in to the database absolutely no problem, it's just the uploaded video does not reach the directory.

On clicking submit the webpage says uploading(1%) and reaches 100% and then it redirects me to the process page... but the video isn't in the directory from the very first line of code on the second page, so if it is uploading, where is it going?

I've checked my php.ini file and everything is enabled and the limits are correct. I can't think of anything else.

This has had me confused for hours now, Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php to `/movies/filename`

Comment: I tested this; move_uploaded_file($target_file , $target_dir); right before the code for handling the database, I got no errors but the video is not in the directory, I don't know where it is!

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, it it not your script that is the problem.
What is the upload limit of your server's php installation ... the default is 2MB.

Check your php.ini file for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size values.

The client will look like it is uploading the file, but the upload will fail.

Comment: I've checked and changed both of these before hand; I set upload_max_filesize to 10000M, which is 10gb, correct? And I set the post_max_size to 0, as the removes the limit. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from

```
 $movieTitle=$_POST["movieTitle"];   
 $movieUrl=$_POST["movieUrl"];
```

to

```
 $movieTitle=$_FILES["movieTitle"];   
  $movieUrl=$_FILES["movieUrl"];
```

Comment: This only creates errors, also this part of the code is sorting the database, the database has no problems, the upload just doesn't arrive at the directory.